# How does Eclipse run a map reduce job?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, hadoop

I followed an article, and managed to run a mapreduce program in eclipse.

following is the pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>



  <groupId>virtusa</groupId>
  <artifactId>fazlan</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>fazlan</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Maven installs necessary jars and when I run the program as a java application, the output is saved as expected.

As I have read Hadoop can be run in 3 modes.

```
1)Single node 
2)psuedo-distributed mode 
3)distributed mode
```

I assume eclipse ran the program in single node configuration.

If we are to install hadoop separately, we will have to edit some xml files to say that we need a specific configuration(I am using Hadoop 2.2 and even for single node configuration I assume it needs some modification in xome of the xml files).

In the above instance I did not change any xml files to say that.How did eclipse figure it out only with the jars.

And also does this method depend on any environment variable other than JAVA_HOME or PATH?(Does Eclipse search for any hadoop installation in my machine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned hadoop can be run in 3 ways

```
Local mode (Only for test purpose no mapreduce daemons needed)
Pseudo distributed mode(1 node cluster)
Distributed mode(Multinode cluster)
```

In local mode, there is no need to run any hadoop daemons(jobtracker, taskters in mr1). This is usually used for test purpose from eclipse But in case of Pseudo distributed and distributed modes, Mapreduce daemons should run. When you run a mapreduce job in pseudo/distributed mode from any client nodes it is necessary to specify the jobtracker node and port number(mapred.job.tracker) in mapred-site.xml, HDFS namenode Host:port in core-site.xml

From eclipse the execution will be in local mode, no daemons will be running(won't connect to any daemons) so there's no need to configure any xml files while submitting jobs

Comment: how can i run a hadoop program in pseudo-distributed mode in eclipse?

Comment: You cannot run a hadoop program in pseudo-distributed mode directly inorder to debug. As mapper and reducer run as separate JVM, eclipse cannot handle that for Hadoop. For debugging pupose you may use local mode or write MR unit testcases etc.